# php.ini-default on Apple OSX Catalina on different locations

Tags: php, macos, macos-catalina

When I type `locate php.ini` in terminal (zsh) it is pointing to `/private/etc/`. But when I type `php --info` it is located in the `/etc` folder. Both of them exists (actually it is php.ini-default). How come the `locate`-command only can find the php.ini-default in `/private/etc` and not in `/etc`? Why are there two of them in two different spots? Is it due to different versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is because /etc is a symlink to /private/etc.

```
total 11
drwxrwxr-x+ 41 root  admin  1312 May  1 03:18 Applications
drwxr-xr-x  67 root  wheel  2144 Mar 28 16:33 Library
drwxr-xr-x@  8 root  wheel   256 Sep 29  2019 System
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  admin   160 Sep 29  2019 Users
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel   224 May  2 01:53 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@ 38 root  wheel  1216 Mar 28 16:30 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    64 Aug 24  2019 cores
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  5554 Apr 30 10:56 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  admin    11 Oct 14  2019 etc -> private/etc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    25 Apr 30 10:56 home -> /System/Volumes/Data/home
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Nov  9 16:27 opt
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel   192 Mar 28 16:32 private
drwxr-xr-x@ 63 root  wheel  2016 Mar 28 16:30 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  admin    11 Oct 14  2019 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 root  wheel   352 Oct 14  2019 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  admin    11 Oct 14  2019 var -> private/var
```

So that's why locate will only find one and not the other. It's the same file!